MySQL Backup (.cfk) file to Microsoft SQL Server
.cfk file is a backup from a MySQL database =>  Microsoft SQL Server
I am currently working on transferring a MySQL database backup file with the extension .cfk to Microsoft SQL Server. I tried the normal backup method and I got this error ... any help or explanation on how I can get through this
https://i.sstatic.net/rUc1vKrk.png

.cfk file is a backup from a MySQL database - what is it? What tool or method produces it? What is its inner format? Anycase - MySQL dump cannot be loaded by SQL Server directly due to the syntax differences.

so what if i want to back it up with MySQL


so what if i want to back it up with MySQL

You can't, it's incompatible. If you want to transfer your database from MySQL to SQL Server, you have two main options:

Script out the entire database as schema and data scripts. This becomes more tedious the larger (by number of objects and data size) your database is.

Use a schema and data migration tool that supports cross-database system compatibility. My personal choice is the SQL Examiner Suite. It costs money, but is simple, effective, and supports all of the main database systems for cross-system migration. (Note I'm not affiliated with them in any way other than a user of the software.) There's probably other tools out there as well, but I've used this one over 10 years, and it's worked great for me. They also have a very responsive support team.


Best of luck!
